# Why isn't the reference counter in boost::shared_ptr volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr

In the `boost::shared_ptr` destructor, this is done:

```
if(--*pn == 0)
{
    boost::checked_delete(px);
    delete pn;
}
```

where `pn` is a pointer to the reference counter, which is typedefed as

```
shared_ptr::count_type -> detail::atomic_count -> long
```

I would have expected the `long` to be `volatile long`, given threaded usage and the non-atomic 0-check-and-deletion in the `shared_ptr` destructor above. Why isn't it volatile?

EDIT:

It turns out I looked at the header used when multi-threaded usage is not specified (atomic_count.hpp). In atomic_count_win32.hpp, the decrement is properly implemented for multithreaded usage.

Comment: Where did you find this code btw?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `volatile` is not necessary for multithreading, and does nothing beneficial, but potentially destroys a number of optimizations.

In order to ensure safe multithreaded access to a variable, the primitive we need is a memory barrier, which provides both the guarantee of `volatile` and a few others (it prevents memory access reordering across the barrier, which volatile doesn't do)

I believe `shared_ptr` uses atomic operations when possible, which implicitly provide a memory barrier. Otherwise it falls back to a mutex, which also provides a memory barrier.

See [Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming) or http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/ for more details

**Edit**
`count_type` is *not* a `long` in the general case. It is *convertible* to a `long`. If you look in `atomic_count.hpp`, the typedef to long is only applied if no threading is available (in which case of course, no synchronization is necessary). Otherwise it uses the implementation defined in `boost/smart_ptr/detail/atomic_count_pthreads.hpp` or `boost/smart_ptr/detail/atomic_count_win32.hpp` or one of the other files listed. And those are synchronized wrapper classes that ensures all operations are done atomically.

Comment: "I believe shared_ptr uses atomic operations when possible" - not in my quoted example with the destructor, which is where my problem lies now...

Comment: Well, making the variable `volatile` wouldn't have changed anything. You're right, decrementing and comparing a long against zero does seem dangerous, but it depends on what the *rest* of the pointer class is doing.

Comment: @jalf: Well, that's were you lost me. ;-)  Right now, in my example, two threads enter the shared_ptr dtor and "the rest of the pointer class" does nothing else.

Comment: @Johann: But again, even if it *is* a bug, how would `volatile` have fixed it?

Comment: @jalf: Ok, sorry, I wasn't explicit enough - I agree (after reading your links) that volatile is out. But given that fact, I couldn't see how your "it depends on what the rest of the pointer class is doing" could be justified in the dtor example. Note - I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want to understand.

Comment: @jalf: Great! My Visual Assist "Goto definition" jumps went nuts and missed that one! atomic_count_win32.hpp perfectly explains my doubts. Thanks!

Comment: @jalf: Edited the question to clarify things.

Answer (score 8):

`volatile` has virtually nothing to do with threading. See [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/).

Comment: Would you say that there's no problem with the above treatment of the counter in the destructor, if executed on different threads?

Answer (score 2):

You are misreading the code. `atomic_count` is defined simply as a long if the code is not using multithreading:

```
#ifndef BOOST_HAS_THREADS

namespace boost
{

namespace detail
{

typedef long atomic_count;

}

}

#elif //... include various platform-specific headers that define atomic_count class

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! Edited the question to clarify things. (Had already accepted jalf's answer)