# Using a variable marked volatile, instead of mutex protected

Tags: c, mutex, volatile

Consider the following example code snippet:

```
void thread_function(void *);

volatile int running = 0;
pthread_t myThread;

int main () {
    running =1;
    pthread_create(myThread, NULL, (void *)thread_function, NULL);

    /* do some stuff */

    /* exit condition met */
    running = 0;
    pthread_join(&myThread);

    /* clean up */

    return 0;
}

void thread_function(void *) 
{
    while(running) {
       /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

I have read lots of posts regarding the volatile keyword and how it should not be used in pretty much all but memory mapped IO but, in this particular circumstance, I cannot understand how it would not perform as expected? Yes, I may get one extra iteration of the while loop (if I'm unlucky enough to get a context switch while I'm setting the 'running' variable to zero), but that doesn't matter.

Is there a good reason why I should mutex protect this variable? Is there something I've overlooked?

Comment: If you are using a multi core cpu volatile i believe is not enough to make changes in different cores immediately visible to all cores. Only the memory barriers that a mutex should use will do that.

Comment: C has an `atomic_bool`.

Comment: Related to [Is it necessary to lock an array that is *only written to* from one thread and *only read from* another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682518/is-it-necessary-to-lock-an-array-that-is-only-written-to-from-one-thread-and)

Comment: Please read this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Comment: wasn't `atomic_bool` rejected?

Comment: @sp2danny: It's in C11, see N1570 7.17.6.

Comment: I'd missed the new atomic qualifier.

The posts are an interesting read, and nothing I didn't already know. 

The fact is I'm maintaining a few applications which use *no* locking or synchronisation at all between threads; just global volatiles - counters, flags, timestamps. It seems crazy and actually would be, if there were any problems - which there aren't, it's processing realtime video too! Could it be a platform / toolchain specific thing? Where volatiles are somehow treated atomically? I could experiment (just finding the time...)

Answer (score 1):

*As written*, your program is safe, because [`pthread_create` and `pthread_join` are memory barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224618/567292). However, as soon as you fill in `/* do some stuff */` you will find that writes to `running` are reordered relative to other data shared between the threads; in this case, this can result in `myThread` terminating *earlier* than expected.

Use a condition variable, or [`atomic_bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).  [Safe to use volatile bool to force another thread to wait? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074028/safe-to-use-volatile-bool-to-force-another-thread-to-wait-c?lq=1)

Comment: I don't think it's safe as written. `pthread_join` synchronizes *when it joins*, not as soon as it starts waiting to join, or at least that's the obvious interpretation of what it should do. I see no reason in OP's program that the thread would *ever* terminate.

Comment: Naturally I didn't think these semantics were safe, and previous experience tells me to always protect access to shared variables... But the fact is I've just started maintaining / adding new features to suite of applications which use *no* proper locking or synchronisation at all between threads; just global volatiles - for anything; counters, flags, timestamps. It seems crazy and actually would be, if there were any noticeable problems - of which there are none, it is processing realtime video too!

Answer (score 0):

if `running` is `volatile`... and changed on another core, you will get the updated version of `running`
... it may not be the next instruction, but a memory barrier will eventually happen and you will get the valid value.

So it isn't safe if you need to guarantee the order of execution, but it will work in a modern multithreaded OS for non-critical operations, like locking a UI element, or sending some network api call.

I have tried using OS X to even make the `volatile` even matter, and I can never get the change to not be seen:

```
#import <pthread.h>
bool flag;

void * secondThread(void *);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    flag = true;
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        pthread_t thread;
        int status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, secondThread, NULL);

        if (status)
        {
            printf("problem with pthread_create %i",errno);
        }
        sleep(4);
        flag = false;
    }
    return 0;
}


void * secondThread(void * arg)
{
    while (flag)
    {
        puts("sleeping\n");
        sleep(1);

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

running with `-Ofast` I get:

```
sleeping

sleeping

sleeping

sleeping
```

my conclusion (and maybe a bad one) is that I include `volatile` for semantic correctness more than I do to actually change the way the program executes.

If you are running an embedded system or RTOS I suspect it may be more important.