# C++11 prototype app design multithreading issue

Tags: multithreading, c++11, race-condition

I have designed a prototype app with the following classes:

- `Ticker` class ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24778929/3616446)) that has an assignable callback that will be executed every tick (specified by `_tickInterval`)
  on a separate thread.
- `SongPosition` class that basically represents a position in a song.
- `BeatClock` class that assigns a callback to `_ticker` which is
  supposed to update `_songpos` **and here I have a problem...**

Here is what `Ticker` class implementation looks like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

class Ticker {
public:
/* TYPES: */
    // Tick interval type in nanoseconds
    typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds tick_interval_type;
    // OnTick callback type
    typedef std::function<void()> on_tick_type;

/* CONSTANTS: */
    // Default ticker interval equal to 120 BPM
    static const tick_interval_type kDefaultTickerInterval;

/* INIT: */
    // Constructs object
    explicit Ticker (tick_interval_type tickInterval) 
    : _onTick ()
    , _tickInterval (tickInterval)
    , _running (false) {}
    // Destructs object
    ~Ticker () {}

/* PROPERTIES: */
    // Sets tick interval to a new value
    void setTickInterval (tick_interval_type tickInterval) {
        _tickIntervalMutex.lock();
        _tickInterval = tickInterval;
        _tickIntervalMutex.unlock();
    }
    // Sets on-tick callback to a new value
    void setOnTick (on_tick_type onTick) { _onTick = onTick; }

/* PUBLIC METHODS: */
    // Starts the ticker
    void start () {
        if (_running) return;
        _running = true;
        std::thread run( &Ticker::loop, this );
        run.detach();
    }
    // Stops the ticker
    void stop () { _running = false; }

private:
/* FIELDS: */
    // OnTick callback, called every tick
    on_tick_type            _onTick;
    // Tick interval between every tick
    tick_interval_type      _tickInterval;
    // Ticker running flag
    volatile bool           _running;
    // Tick interval mutex for thread safety
    std::mutex              _tickIntervalMutex;

/* PRIVATE METHODS: */
    // Inner loop executed on a separate thread to produce ticks
    void loop () {
        tick_interval_type ti;
        while (_running) {
            std::thread run (_onTick);
            run.detach();

            _tickIntervalMutex.lock();
            ti = _tickInterval;
            _tickIntervalMutex.unlock();

            std::this_thread::sleep_for( ti );
        }
    }
};

// Default ticker interval equal to 120 BPM
const Ticker::tick_interval_type Ticker::kDefaultTickerInterval (625000000UL / 120UL);
```

Here is what `SongPosition` class implementation looks like:

```
#include <cstdint>

class SongPosition {
public:
/* INIT: */
    // Constructs song position instance: Ticks | Beats | Measures
    SongPosition (uint8_t ticks = 0u, uint8_t beats = 0u, uint16_t measures = 0u) {
        _ticks = ticks;
        _beats = beats;
        _measures = measures;
    }
    ~SongPosition () {}

/* PROPERTIES:: */
    // Counts from 0..95
    uint8_t ticks () const { return _ticks; }
    // Counts the quarter notes 0..3
    uint8_t beats () const { return _beats; }
    // Counts the measures 0..65535
    uint16_t measures () const { return _measures; }
    // Current meter location, sixteens-notes counter
    uint16_t meter () const { return (_beats << 2) | (_measures << 4); }

/* METHODS: */
    // Resets meter counters
    void reset () {
        _ticks = 0u;
        _beats = 0u;
        _measures = 0u;
    }
    // Resets ticks counter
    void resetTicks () { _ticks = 0u; }
    // Resets beats counter
    void resetBeats () { _beats = 0u; }
    // Increments ticks counter
    void incrementTicks () { ++_ticks; }
    // Increments beats counter
    void incrementBeats () { ++_beats; }
    // Increments measures counter
    void incrementMeasures () { ++_measures; }
    // Decrements measures counter
    void decrementMeasures () { --_measures; }

    bool operator== (const SongPosition& other) const {
        if (_ticks == other.ticks() 
            && _beats == other.beats() 
            && _measures == other.measures())   return true;
        else return false;
    }
    bool operator!= (const SongPosition& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
/* FIELDS: */
    // Counts from 0..95
    uint8_t     _ticks;
    // Counts the quarter notes 0..3
    uint8_t     _beats;
    // Counts the measures 0..65535
    uint16_t    _measures;
};

inline bool operator<  (const SongPosition& lhs, const SongPosition& rhs) {
    if (lhs.measures() < rhs.measures()) return true;
    else if (lhs.measures() == rhs.measures()) {
        if (lhs.beats() < rhs.beats()) return true;
        else if (lhs.beats() == rhs.beats()) {
            if (lhs.ticks() < rhs.ticks()) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;
}
inline bool operator>  (const SongPosition& lhs, const SongPosition& rhs) {
    return rhs < lhs;
}
inline bool operator<= (const SongPosition& lhs, const SongPosition& rhs) {
    return !(lhs > rhs);
}
inline bool operator>= (const SongPosition& lhs, const SongPosition& rhs) {
    return !(lhs < rhs);
}
```

And finally here is what `BeatClock` class implementation looks like (**the problem one**):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include "SongPosition.h"
#include "Ticker.h"

class BeatClock {
public:
/* INNER CLASSES: */
    // Inner state of beat clock
    enum class State : uint8_t {
        kStopped,
        kRunning,
        kPaused
    };

/* CONSTANTS: */
    // Clock pre-start delay to give a slave time to prepare (1ms)
    static const std::chrono::milliseconds kPreStartDelay;

/* CONSTRUCTORS/DISTRUCTORS: */
    // Constructs object
    BeatClock () 
    : _bpm (120UL)
    , _ticker (Ticker::kDefaultTickerInterval)
    , _songpos ()
    , _precount () {
        _ticker.setOnTick( [&] {
            _tickerMutex.lock();
            _songpos.incrementTicks();
            if (_songpos.ticks() == 96U) {      // next beat...
                _songpos.resetTicks();
                _songpos.incrementBeats();
                if (_songpos.beats() == 4U) {   // next measure...
                    _songpos.resetBeats();
                    _songpos.incrementMeasures();
                }
            }
            if (_precount == 0U) {
                _precount = 4U;
                printf( "Send - RealTimeClock: %2i | %1i | %05i", 
                    _songpos.ticks(), _songpos.beats(), _songpos.ticks() );
            }
            ++_precount;
            _tickerMutex.unlock();
        } );
        _state = State::kStopped;
    }
    // Destructs object
    ~BeatClock () {}

/* PROPERTIES: */
    // Gets current BPM value 
    uint64_t bpm () const { return _bpm; }
    // Sets current BPM to a new value
    void setBpm (uint64_t bpm) { 
        _bpm = bpm;
        Ticker::tick_interval_type span (625000000UL / _bpm);
        _ticker.setTickInterval( span );
    }

/* PUBLIC METHODS: */
    // Starts if currently stopped / Pauses if currently running / Resumes if currently paused
    void start () {
        switch (_state)
        {
        case State::kStopped:   // start...
            _songpos.reset();
            this->sendMeter();
            printf( "Send - RealTimeStart" );
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( kPreStartDelay );
            _state = State::kRunning;
            _ticker.start();
            break;
        case State::kRunning:   // pause...
            _ticker.stop();
            _state = State::kPaused;
            break;
        case State::kPaused:    // continue...
            printf( "Send - RealTimeContinue" );
            _state = State::kRunning;
            _ticker.start();
            break;
        }
    }
    // Stops if currently running or paused / Resets if currently stopped
    void stop () {
        switch (_state)
        {
        case State::kStopped:   // reset...
            _songpos.reset();
            this->sendMeter();
            printf( "Send - RealTimeStop" );
            break;
        case State::kRunning:
        case State::kPaused:    // stop...
            printf( "Send - RealTimeStop" );
            _ticker.stop();
            _precount = 0U;
            _state = State::kStopped;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Increments measure and resets sub-counters
    void forward () {
        if (_state == State::kRunning) _ticker.stop();
        _songpos.resetTicks();
        _songpos.resetBeats();
        _songpos.incrementMeasures();
        _precount = 0U;
        this->sendMeter();
        if (_state == State::kRunning) _ticker.start();
    }
    // Decrements measure and resets sub-counters
    void rewind () {
        if (_state == State::kRunning) _ticker.stop();
        _songpos.resetTicks();
        _songpos.resetBeats();
        if (_songpos.measures() > 0U) _songpos.decrementMeasures();
        _precount = 0U;
        this->sendMeter();
        if (_state == State::kRunning) _ticker.start();
    }

private:
/* FIELDS: */
    // Current BPM value
    uint64_t        _bpm;
    // Used for generating tick events.
    Ticker          _ticker;
    // Current song position
    SongPosition    _songpos;
    // Clock precount to scale from 96 to 24 ppqn (0..3)
    uint8_t         _precount;
    // Transport state  
    State           _state;
    // Ticker mutex for thread safety
    std::mutex      _tickerMutex;

/* PRIVATE METHODS: */
    // Sends Song-Position MIDI message
    void sendMeter () {
        printf( "Send - SongPosition: %i", _songpos.meter() );
    }
};

// Clock pre-start delay to give a slave time to prepare (1ms)
const std::chrono::milliseconds BeatClock::kPreStartDelay (1);
```

`_onTick` callback is not working as expected, updating `_songpos` randomly (because of data-races?)
Can you please advice how to update `_songpos` in controllable way from a callback (which is running on a separate thread)?

Here is what I'm expecting to be logged (that is 24 ticks per beat and 4 beats per measure):

```
Send - SongPosition: 0
Send - RealTimeStart            // begin...
Send - RealTimeClock:  2 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  5 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  9 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 13 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 17 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 21 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 25 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 29 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 33 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 37 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 41 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 45 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 49 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 53 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 57 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 61 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 65 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 69 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 73 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 77 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 81 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 85 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 89 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 93 | 0 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  1 | 1 | 00000    // next beat..
Send - RealTimeClock:  5 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  9 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 13 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 17 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 21 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 25 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 29 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 33 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 37 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 41 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 45 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 49 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 53 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 57 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 61 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 65 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 69 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 73 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 77 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 81 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 85 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 89 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 93 | 1 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  1 | 2 | 00000    // next beat..
Send - RealTimeClock:  5 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  9 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 13 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 17 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 21 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 25 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 29 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 33 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 37 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 41 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 45 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 49 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 53 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 57 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 61 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 65 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 69 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 73 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 77 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 81 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 85 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 89 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 93 | 2 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  1 | 3 | 00000    // next beat..
Send - RealTimeClock:  5 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  9 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 13 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 17 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 21 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 25 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 29 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 33 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 37 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 41 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 45 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 49 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 53 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 57 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 61 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 65 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 69 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 73 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 77 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 81 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 85 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 89 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock: 93 | 3 | 00000
Send - RealTimeClock:  1 | 0 | 00001    // next measure and once again...
Send - RealTimeStop         // enough. :)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot find what data type `_songpos` is. Consider making that an `std::atomic<type>`. You can find data races by checking if any variable can potentially be written by 2 threads or written and read by 2 threads concurrently. I am too lazy to do that for you.

Comment: Please turn this into a runnable program. It should not be hard, I've done it in like 5 minutes, and my version exhibits no random behaviour you describe.

Comment: @nwp `_songpos` is instance of `SongPosition` class I described. I suppose that data-race it's exactly what is happening with this variable. Thanks for advice, I'll try to wrap it in `std::atomic<SongPosition>`

Comment: @n.m. it is a runnable program (on windows). That's how I know that there is a problem... You ran it on windows? Can you show me the log output you get?

Comment: I didn't run in on Windows. I don't have cocos2d, have no idea what it is and why it is needed here, and no desire to install it. Remove reference to cocos2d, replace `log()` with `printf()` and add main(), so that it is pure standard c++11. Also add desired output.

Comment: @n.m. sorry, that is my fault, cocos2d is unnecessary in the implementation. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works fine and I haven't noticed any race condition. Consider this string `log( "Send - RealTimeClock: %2i | %1i | %05i", _songpos.ticks(), _songpos.beats(), _songpos.ticks() );`
It writes `ticks | beats | ticks` about every one second. Perhaps, you mean measures instead one of ticks? Proper output looks like the following (the last value is a measure)

```
Send - SongPosition: 0,
Send - RealTimeStart
Send - RealTimeClock: 1 | 0 | 0
Send - RealTimeClock: 61 | 2 | 0
Send - RealTimeClock: 25 | 1 | 1
Send - RealTimeClock: 85 | 3 | 1
Send - RealTimeClock: 49 | 2 | 2
Send - RealTimeClock: 13 | 1 | 3
```

And it is ok. You can check if it is race condition just changing thread start to simple function invocation.

And one remark. `_tickerMutex` appears to be unsafe in your case. If you use mutex to protect some data from simultaneous change then use it in ***every*** case when the data is changed. So _`songpos` is protected in your ticker lambda function but is unsafe in all functions like start, stop etc.

Comment: Hvarnah, there is a mistake in printing, it should be `ticks | beats | measures` of course, thank you. Now it's make more sense but it's still not what I expected to be printed out. I'm expecting to see 24 ticks per beat and 4 beats per measure but the printing is partial or just not printed entirely... really don't know... Please look at the question, I'll add what I expect to see there.

Comment: @mikeg I see, you want to output values every 4 ticks but count from 4 to 0. I think it is supposed to be from 0 to 4
`if (_precount == 0U) {
     _precount = 4U;
..
 ++_precount;`

Comment: Hvarnah, thanks, of course!!! this should be `--_precount` instead! Well, I need to take a break some time and let the eyes rest... Thank you very much!