# A program with two thread, one thread increase the global var, other thread decrease the same var, will the var always right?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking

I'm confuse with the problem, it just come up when I review someone's `C++` code.

For example in C++:

```
// Global var
int g_var = 0;

// thread 1 call Func1() forever:
void Func1() {
  ++g_var;
}

// thread 2 call Func2() forever:
void Func2() {
  --g_var;
}
```

Define the `Func1` call times `times1`, `Func2` call times `times2`

- Does `times1 - times2` always `= g_var`?
- What if the code is in `C` not in `C++`?
- What if the `g_var` use `volatile` decoration?
- Does using atomic_increase/atomic_decrease is the only right way?

What I think, it should use `violatile` in `C++`, not ecessary use atomic operation like `InterlockedIncrement` in Windows, because the assembly code is just one line, one `add` instruction:

```
mov         eax,1
add         dword ptr [a],eax
```

Comment: `int g_var = 0;` should be [`std::atomic<int> g_var = 0;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming)

Comment: Which assembly instructions are generated for _one_ particular platform doesn't matter.  There are processors which would need separate instructions for reading and writing the value.  And even one instruction doesn't necessarily mean it is atomic!

Comment: Note that *not* using atomic operations explicitly *might* still be compiled to an assembly instruction which is atomic (i.e. the standard doesn't forbid it!). But you don't have a guarantee that it will do that unless you use atomics explicitly. Even worse: it will be hard to debug since you might think it works, but that's only your luck on this particular machine, but when porting to a different architecture it might break! That's often the case with undefined behavior: it might work in one setup, but isn't guaranteed to do on others. Very frustrating.

Comment: `violatile` describes it quite pictorially ;) ...

Comment: thanks all, now I got more understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your questions in the order of their appearance:

- No, your program has undefined behavior. It might be the case that thread 1 reads the variable (to be increased), gets interrupted, then thread 2 reads the variable (to be decreased), decreases it and writes it back (so it is minus one compared to the value we started with), then thread 1 continues, increases its memorized old value and writes it back to the variable, resulting in plus one compared to the value we started with.
- The language doesn't change anything here.
- `volatile` only guarantees that a single thread might not cache the value of the variable, i.e. `++g_var; ++g_var;` will read the variable, increase, write, read, increase, write. It is not replaced by `g_var += 2` by the optimizer. But the thread can still be interrupted in between reading and writing which is the dangerous part.
- That is a perfect example where you need atomic operations. Either use atomic operations on an `int`, or use the `std::atomic<int>` wrapper which automatically does that for you when you call the normal operators, making your code more readable.

  Simply replacing `int g_var` with `std::atomic<int> g_var` solves any problems.

Answer (score 1):

- No, because the code is not thread safe.
- C instead of C++ doesn't matter.
- `volatile` doesn't help, it prevents ”caching” the value in a register or other optimizations, but doesn't make the operations atomic.
- Yes.  Or no, if implementing such functions yourself with a locking mechanism is an option.