# std::is_trivially_default_constructible and volatile types

Tags: c++, c++11, volatile, type-traits

Looking at the answer to this question:

[std::is_trivially_copyable - Why are volatile scalar types not trivially copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098055/stdis-trivially-copyable-why-are-volatile-scalar-types-not-trivially-copyabl)

I see that the standard says a type is not trivially copyable if it has a volatile member, even when that member is a basic type.  This appears to be due to a need to ensure that volatile members are updated atomically, and the byte-by-byte copy implied by trivial copyability can be violated.

But doesn't this also imply that is_trivially_default_constructible should fail on these types?

It seems that this is the correct check to see if a class can "correctly" be zero initialized (memset-able) in the same way is_trivially_copyable is used to detect memcpy-ability.  And the memset may be non-atomic for the same basic reason.

However maybe this assumption is wrong.  Is it incorrect to assume that a trivially constructible class is memset-initializable?  If it is incorrect, what is the correct check to determine this?

To be a little clearer, I'm not assuming that is_trivially_default_constructible actually tells me anything about the semantic correctness of memset constructibility, zero initializability, or any of that. I just mean that it can tell me if that is possible in the same way as memcpy-ability.  Maybe is_trivially_copyable is sufficient for all cases, since construction as a buffer is logically equivalent to copying some (possibly static or algorithmically definable) buffer into the object after construction?

Comment: "*volatile members are updated atomically*" There's nothing in the standard that requires that `volatile` values are updated atomically. You can have data races on `volatile` values.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, I'm afraid I do not understand very well the actual "memory tearing" issue discussed in the link. It is possible that there is something about this that distinguishes copy from construction. Specifically, initializing from some byte buffer (or a byte fill) and copying byte buffers can be identical operations, so I'm not understanding the distinction in the standard.

Comment: CWG defect 2094, mentioned in your link, was applied to the C++ working draft. A type is trivially copyable if it has a volatile member - see  http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#9 or http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#ctor-11 etc