# What memory barriers are there in C++98?

Tags: multithreading, arm, volatile, c++98, mbed

I've stumbled about this thread: [Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming)

and stumbled upon the following in the top voted answer...

> However, memory barriers also ensure that all pending reads/writes are executed when the barrier is reached, so it effectively gives us everything we need by itself, making volatile unnecessary. We can just remove the volatile qualifier entirely.
>
> Since C++11, atomic variables (std::atomic) give us all of the relevant guarantees.

I'm working on C++98 capable platform, so what memory barrier was available for C++98? I've tried to use mutex for mbed, but I can't logically determine if a mutex is a sufficient way to protect, for example, both a serial write and read happening in two simultaneous threads, since I don't have enough confidence in regards to thread-safety.

What is an easy way to access a simple shared resource in c++98?

Comment: You need a platform specific answer; please add your platform/OS to your question.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm working on mbed, so a microcontroller. To be more specific, LPC1768.

Comment: Even with sufficient barriers, there are stuff in C++ that only be done with compiler support, such as dynamic initialization of function static variables on first invocation of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++98 Standard is single threaded (threads do not exist) so none in the standard.  You will however have OS/Platform specific memory barriers.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't logically determine if a mutex is a sufficient way to
>   protect, for example, both a serial write and read happening in two
>   simultaneous threads

If the mutex code cannot guarantee that, they it's by definition broken. We would have to see that code to check whether it was properly done.