# threading, if-else statement, both are wrong after context switch, what will happen

Tags: c++

Example

```
int a = 8;
if(a < 9){
 something1();
}
else{
 something2();
}
```

what will happen if there was a context switch right before the if statment (after the init of a) which will change a to a=11,
and then return to the above code, and before getting to else, another context switch which will change a to a= 8, and again return to the above code. will it still be in the else statment?

thanks

Comment: It should skip the else unless you return to the if again. Because else is only entered when if is not true.

Comment: You'd need to make `a` `volatile`, or the compiler would replace everything with `something1();`

Comment: @Andreas -- `volatile` is never the right answer to multi-threading issues. If `a` is shared between threads, the right answer is to make it `std::atomic<int> a = 8;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker [Ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming), but it would still prevent the compiler from optimizing away the necessary operations in the OP's example.

Comment: @Andreas -- the behavior of the code in the question is undefined. Marking `a` as `volatile` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` can be modified by some other thread then the code **must** synchronize the two threads somehow. The simplest way, which seems appropriate here, is to make `a` atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> a = 8;
```

Now multiple threads can read and write the value of `a` with well-defined behavior. The actual value the you see depends on the order of the reads and writes, of course, and the language definition can't help you with that. But making `a` atomic ensures that every read will see a value that was actually written, and that the compiler won't optimize out the test in the `if` statement.

Comment: johnTheSo99 -- it's customary to wait a day or so before accepting an answer. Some folks don't read questions that have accepted answers, so by accepting early you risk not getting a superior answer.

Comment: While this is a perfect and very important advise, this does not answer the question "what will happen if ...".

Comment: @sebrockm -- "what will happen if ..." cannot be answered.

Comment: Well, the answer is UB.

Comment: @sebrockm </shrug>

Answer (score 0):

if-statements are usually implemented with *conditional jumps* in assembly code. But they don't have to be. E.g take this code for example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 42)
        return 62;
    else
        return 31;
}
```

which clang compiles as (with optimization):

```
main: # @main
  cmp edi, 42
  mov ecx, 62
  mov eax, 31
  cmovg eax, ecx
  ret
```

Anyways you will usually have a single compare somewhere, i.e the variable is only checked once. In this case the variable is checked at the `cmp edi, 42` statement.

In general the behaviour is simply undefined.

Comment: @Sebasitan Hoffmann, thanks, but genrally can it ignore both the if and else in some undefined situation (or it must enter at least on of the statement)?

Comment: @johnTheSo99 it's impossible to reason about undefined behaviour in a general fashion. Usually it should'nt be possible but that doesn't mean it could never happen. If you have concrete code you can always check the resulting assembly.

Comment: @johnTheSo99 It is e.g very likely that you don't even see any change in the variable (unless declared `volatile`) because it is stored inside some register (like in this case)

Comment: @Sebasitan Hoffmann, in the example that you showned, is it possible to not get into both the if and else statement?

Comment: @johnTheSo99 No it isn't in this particular example. Have you read the answer?

Comment: @Sebasitan Hoffmann, yes, but I wanted to make sure that I understand it correctly, thanks.