# How to change the value of a variable without the compiler knowing?

Tags: c, compilation, volatile

I want to verify the role of volatile by this method. But my inline assembly code doesn't seem to be able to modify the value of i without the compiler knowing. According to the articles I read, I only need to write assembly code like  `__asm { mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 20h }`, I think I write the same as what he did.

actual output:

```
before = 10
after = 123
```

expected output:

```
before = 10
after = 10
```

Article link: https://www.runoob.com/w3cnote/c-volatile-keyword.html

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    // volatile int i = 10;
    int i = 10;

    a = i;
    printf("before = %d\n", a);

    // Change the value of i in memory without letting the compiler know.
    // I can't run the following statement here, so I wrote one myself
    // mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 20h
    asm("movl $123, -12(%rbp)");

    b = i;
    printf("after = %d\n", b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to verify the role of `volatile` ...

You can't.

If a variable is not `volatile`, the compiler **may** optimize; it does **not need** to do this.

A compiler may always treat **any** variable as `volatile`.

> How to change the value of a variable without the compiler knowing?

Create a second thread writing to the variable.

**Example**

The following example is for Linux (under Windows, you need a different function than `pthread_create()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int testVar;
volatile int waitVar;

void * otherThread(void * dummy)
{
    while(waitVar != 2) { /* Wait */ }
    testVar = 123;
    waitVar = 3;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pt;
    waitVar = 1;
    pthread_create(&pt, 0, otherThread, NULL);
    testVar = 10;
    waitVar = 2;
    while(waitVar != 3) { /* Wait */ }
    printf("%d\n", testVar - 10);
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile with `gcc -O0 -o x x.c -lpthread`, the compiler does not optimize and works like all variables are `volatile`. `printf()` prints 113.

If you compile with `-O3` instead of `-O0`, `printf()` prints 0.

If you replace `int testVar` by `volatile int testVar`, `printf()` always prints 113 (independent of `-O0`/`-O3`).

(Tested with the GCC 9.4.0 compiler.)

Comment: *If you replace `int testVar` by `volatile int testVar`, `printf()` always prints 113 (independent of `-O0`/`-O3`).* That is not guaranteed to happen.  See [**Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming).  Also see [Hans Boehm's description of just what `volatile` means](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html).  For one, it doesn't mean "atomic".

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are right. Theoretically, the threads may access different CPU caches...