# Run a signal handler without issuing a signal

Tags: c, signals, posix

Is there a mechanism where I can run a signal handler in another thread without invoking a signal?

I want to send a notification to a different thread and I was wondering if it can be done by interrupting its execution and make it run a callback while the thread is paused.

If there is no standard way to do it in POSIX, A Linux feature will also be useful. Also, if this feature exists, how would I block "signals" in the receiving thread?

Comment: You probably don't want to use signals for this. You can't send data with the signal. Better would be to use SysV IPC (`msgsnd/msgrcv`) for this. The receiving thread can poll using `IPC_NOWAIT`. I've done this many times with great success in commercial product mission critical applications. I have a number of SO answers for SysV IPC, but this one may help: [In C, is storing data in local variables in threads akin to creating a local copy? AKA Does this Threadpool synchronization make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762865/5382650) You could put the `msgrcv` in the sighandler

Comment: @CraigEstey, I agree that signals are pretty poor for IPC, but they are the only mechanism I know for preempting a thread to run code outside its normal flow of execution (see the OP's 2nd paragraph).

Comment: "without invoking a signal" "can be done by interrupting its execution" That's what signals do, and nothing else does.

Comment: What can be done from a signal handler is extremely limited. So, you "interrupt" the thread but unless you're willing the do `setjmp/longjmp` you can't do much. You might be able to use `swapcontext` et. al. but rearchitecting to use `msg*` will produce a much more robust system. IMO, the fallacy here is that you have to "seize" the thread and get it to change instead of sending a message to do different things. We'd need to know more about your intended thread architecture.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I question OP's _necessity_ to preempt a thread (that is just looping otherwise). Adding non-blocking polling checks works well (even in critical scenarios). What threading model is OP using (e.g. master/slave, threadpool, etc.)? Even the [linux] kernel doesn't do this. It never forces a thread to do something _without_ knowledge/cooperation of the target thread. In short, without more specific info, I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: To be clear, I do know about all those other mechanisms of IPC, I was just wondering if there is a way to do it the way I described in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a mechanism where I can run a signal handler in another thread without invoking a signal?

There is a variety of ways for one thread to request specific work from another.  Signals are only one.  HOWEVER, ...

> I want to send a notification to a different thread and I was wondering if it can be done by interrupting its execution and make it run a callback while the thread is paused.

... there is no way for a userspace thread to *preempt* another thread to make it perform work *outside its normal flow of execution*.  Only the kernel can do that, and the mechanism for it is signal delivery.  (One thread can request that a signal be delivered to another, so I'm drawing a somewhat fine distinction here, but the kernel needs to accept the request and to perform the actual signal delivery.)

> If there is no standard way to do it in POSIX, A Linux feature will also be useful.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no Linux-specific feature available for this, either.

Comment: I was reading about `makecontext`/`swapcontext` and it seems that it almost does what I was looking for, however I can't find if I can swap the context from another thread

Comment: @JimMorrison, no, you cannot swap a different thread's context.  And I am inclined to doubt that in one thread you can safely use a context that was created in a different one.  `makecontext` and `swapcontext` provide a (now) little-used basis for userspace, *cooperative* multithreading, but you're already using (p)threads, and you have asked for a preemptive solution.  These are not the droids you're looking for.