# Can a blocked signal wake up a process from a semaphore waiting queue?

Tags: c, unix, signals, semaphore

i have this program that forks itself a lot of times (resetting its proccess block via execve every time) and another program that send signals to it so it can fork again. In the handler I blocked every signal (via sigprocmask) so that i dont receive a double signal but somehow it wakes up from the semaphore even if the signals are blocked. (the program that sends the signals doest send KILL and the other signal that cannot be blocked)

So a blocked signal can wake up a process from a waiting state? (I used semop for the semaphore wait)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

sigset_t all_signals;

void sigusr1_handler(int signo) {
        printf("SIGUSER1 received \n");
        sigfillset(&all_signals);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &all_signals, NULL);
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    bzero(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = sigusr1_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem? All the forking and exec'ing should be unnecessary, just a program that creates a signal handler, blocks signals, and waits on a semaphore.

Comment: There's no semaphores in your code?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah of course, I'll edit my post so you can see a test code. Sigprocmask should be signal safe as specified in the man Page (man signal-safety) but both the signals are send and received in this case (with raise) meaning that they weren't blocked in the first signal handling.
Ah and the answer to my question is no, a blocked signal can't wake up a semaphore waiting on semop , but there is a problem with using sigprocmask inside a signal handler.

Comment: @Shawn I noticed that those don't cause problems with blocked signals, the problem is using sigprocmask in a signal handler

Comment: Instead of using `sigprocmask` in the handler, can't you use the `sa_mask` field when calling `sigaction`? I suspect you're running into a race condition where the signal arrives before you call `sigprocmask()`

Comment: @Barmar doesn't the sa_mask block signals only while the handler is running?

Comment: Yes, I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: No I need to receive it once and after that it should block all the signals, if I put sigprocmask in the main it work but that leaves a frame of time where another signal could arrive. I want the handler to block all signals so that it's impossible to receive signals until I unblock them again with sigprocmask in the main

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual problem code, in a stripped-down fashion.  I think you want to block and [accept](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html) signals, rather than allow them to be [delivered](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).  But without the demonstrative code, we cannot really help.

Comment: No problem, I cannot actually share the code but I already got a solution using message queues or by using a global flag in the process

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. `sa_mask` only blocks signals while the signal handler is running.
2. It does this by ORing in `sa_mask` to the current mask before calling the handler.
3. After the handler exits, the *original* mask is restored.
4. So, although `sigprocmask` *is* valid/safe inside a signal handler, none of the changes will be preserved when the handler exits.
5. Calling `printf` from a signal handler is *unsafe* (because it uses `malloc/free`). So, to do a *safe* `printf`, one *can* do `sprintf` followed by `write`

---

Here is some modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

sigset_t all_signals;

#define safe_printf(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        char buf[100]; \
        size_t len = sprintf(buf,_fmt); \
        write(1,buf,len); \
    } while (0)

#define SIGSHOW(_signo) \
    { .sig_name = #_signo, .sig_no = _signo },

#define SIGALL(_cmd) \
    _cmd(SIGHUP) \
    _cmd(SIGINT) \
    _cmd(SIGQUIT) \
    _cmd(SIGILL) \
    _cmd(SIGTRAP) \
    _cmd(SIGABRT) \
    _cmd(SIGIOT) \
    _cmd(SIGBUS) \
    _cmd(SIGFPE) \
    _cmd(SIGKILL) \
    _cmd(SIGUSR1) \
    _cmd(SIGSEGV) \
    _cmd(SIGUSR2) \
    _cmd(SIGPIPE) \
    _cmd(SIGALRM) \
    _cmd(SIGTERM) \
    _cmd(SIGSTKFLT) \
    _cmd(SIGCHLD) \
    _cmd(SIGCONT) \
    _cmd(SIGSTOP) \
    _cmd(SIGTSTP) \
    _cmd(SIGTTIN) \
    _cmd(SIGTTOU) \
    _cmd(SIGURG) \
    _cmd(SIGXCPU) \
    _cmd(SIGXFSZ) \
    _cmd(SIGVTALRM) \
    _cmd(SIGPROF) \
    _cmd(SIGWINCH) \
    _cmd(SIGIO) \
    _cmd(SIGPWR) \
    _cmd(SIGSYS)

struct sigshow {
    const char *sig_name;
    int sig_no;
};

struct sigshow siglist[] = {
    SIGALL(SIGSHOW)
    { .sig_name = NULL },
};

void
showmask(const sigset_t *set,const char *who)
{
    char buf[1000];
    char *rhs = buf;
    char *lhs = buf;
    sigset_t mask;

    if (set == NULL) {
        set = &mask;
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,NULL,&mask);
    }

    rhs += sprintf(rhs,"showmask (from %s):\n",who);

    for (struct sigshow *show = siglist;  show->sig_name != NULL;  ++show) {
        if (sigismember(set,show->sig_no))
            rhs += sprintf(rhs," %s",show->sig_name);
        if ((rhs - lhs) >= 66) {
            rhs += sprintf(rhs,"\n");
            lhs = rhs;
        }
    }

    rhs += sprintf(rhs,"\n");

    write(1,buf,rhs - buf);
}

void
sigusr1_handler(int signo)
{
    //safe_printf("SIGUSER1 received \n");
    showmask(NULL,"handler/ENTER");
    sigfillset(&all_signals);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &all_signals, NULL);
    showmask(NULL,"handler/EXIT");
}

int
main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    showmask(NULL,"main/ENTER");

    bzero(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = sigusr1_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask,SIGUSR1);

    showmask(&sa.sa_mask,"main/sa_mask");
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    showmask(NULL,"main/preraise1");
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    showmask(NULL,"main/preraise2");
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    showmask(NULL,"main/postraise2");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
showmask (from main/ENTER):

showmask (from main/sa_mask):
 SIGUSR1
showmask (from main/preraise1):

showmask (from handler/ENTER):
 SIGUSR1
showmask (from handler/EXIT):
 SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGILL SIGTRAP
 SIGABRT SIGIOT SIGBUS SIGFPE SIGUSR1 SIGSEGV SIGUSR2 SIGPIPE SIGALRM
 SIGTERM SIGSTKFLT SIGCHLD SIGCONT SIGTSTP SIGTTIN SIGTTOU SIGURG SIGXCPU
 SIGXFSZ SIGVTALRM SIGPROF SIGWINCH SIGIO SIGPWR SIGSYS
showmask (from main/preraise2):

showmask (from handler/ENTER):
 SIGUSR1
showmask (from handler/EXIT):
 SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGILL SIGTRAP
 SIGABRT SIGIOT SIGBUS SIGFPE SIGUSR1 SIGSEGV SIGUSR2 SIGPIPE SIGALRM
 SIGTERM SIGSTKFLT SIGCHLD SIGCONT SIGTSTP SIGTTIN SIGTTOU SIGURG SIGXCPU
 SIGXFSZ SIGVTALRM SIGPROF SIGWINCH SIGIO SIGPWR SIGSYS
showmask (from main/postraise2):
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Oh I understand thanks for explaining. Ik about the printf being unsafe but it was only for the test.

Although, for this *limited* test case, it might be safe (because the base level is *not* doing any `printf` or `malloc`), I wanted to be sure. Especially, since I added some base level `printf`.

> So are there any effective ways of blocking all signals in a handler for the whole process or it can only be done in the main? –
> David

I was thinking that doing `getcontext`, modifying `uc_sigmask`, and calling `setcontext` *might* work. So, I tried it. I just got [effectively] an infinite loop where the handler is *never* exited.

More/better trickery with this *might* be possible. **But...** I don't think it's worth the effort as it would be a bit fragile if it could be made to work at all.

Without seeing all of your code, it's difficult to give a definitive answer. That is, what the sender is doing, what the receiver is doing when *not* processing a signal, etc.

But, a better proposition is to rearchitect the "signaling" mechanism.

That is, `SIGUSR1` is *not* queued. So, a program that does *rapid* signalling could race against the receiver and some signals could be lost. Better to use a *realtime* signal because they are *queued*

Also, signals are asynchronous to the recipient. They are designed for *exceptional* conditions and not to send "messages" between processes.

There are race conditions galore in the recipient between receiving the signal (in the handler) and masking so the child process you do `fork/execve` for doesn't get the signals (even with RT signals).

A better way would be to use SysV IPC to send/receive messsages (i.e. `msgsnd/msgrcv`). With this mechanism, the recipient is *not* racing against itself.

Also, we can eliminate the semaphore altogether.

I've used SysV IPC for many similar purposes in commercial products for realtime systems with great success.

For a small example of this, loosely derived from my production code, see my answer: [In C, is storing data in local variables in threads akin to creating a local copy? AKA Does this Threadpool synchronization make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762865/5382650)

Comment: Oh I understand thanks for explaining. Ik about the printf being unsafe but it was only for the test. So are there any effective ways of blocking all signals in a handler for the whole process or it can only be done in the main?

Comment: Nah yeah a solution with message queues is better, idk why I haven't thought about it earlier since I've already used some of those in the project. Thanks again for everything